# Detox IOS - tests fail due to continuous animation error, disableSynchronization not working

Tags: detox

Please bear with me, I am new to Detox!  I am currently evaluating Detox as an alternative to a well known very slow black box automation tool!

**ENV**

- Detox:v9.0.1
- xCode:v9.4.1
- macOS:High Sierra 10.13.2

executing tests using:
    `detox test --debug-synchronization --loglevel trace`

I am writing an automation test that logs into our app and verifies the landing page.  After logging in, I am unable to identify any elements as the error that I am getting is:

```
"appState": "Waiting for an animation to finish. Continuous animations may never finish and must be stopped explicitly. Animations attached to hidden view may still be running in the background.\nWaiting for view's draw or layout pass to complete."
```

and

```
detox[94060] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: 
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
detox[94060] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector 
@selector(removeInactiveFingerTips) on DTXTouchVisualizerWindow
detox[94060] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync App State: undefined
detox[94060] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main- 
thread
detox[94060] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] 
{"type":"cleanupDone","messageId":8,"params":{}}
```

I have added URLs to the blacklist which helped remove some errors and now I've wrapped my steps in numerous combinations of `device.disableSynchronization` and `device.enableSynchronization` which doesn't seem to be helping.  Please see my current version of the test:

```
describe('Signon and browse', () => {
beforeEach(async () => {
  await device.reloadReactNative();
});

 it('I log into the app', async () => {
     await element(by.id('input_username')).replaceText('mysername');
     await element(by.id('input_password')).replaceText('mypassword');
     await element(by.id('button-signon')).tap();
     await device.disableSynchronization();
     await waitFor(element(by.id('app-title'))).toHaveValue('DISCOVER').withTimeout(20000);
     await device.enableSynchronization();
 })
});
```

I am a test automation developer and not the ReactNative developer for the app, therefore I am unsure if there is something that needs to change within the actual ReactNative code - which will be a dealbreaker for us!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

From the Detox documentation for `waitFor()`, `toHaveValue()` should be accompanied with `expect` statement. https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.waitFor.md#tohavevaluevalue

Add `expect()` after `waitFor()`as shown below.

```
await waitFor(element(by.id('app-title'))).toHaveValue('DISCOVER').withTimeout(20000);
await expect(element(by.id('app-title'))).toHaveValue('DISCOVER');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I have just tried your suggestion and unfortunately I am still faced with the same issue.  Is this the point where I need to look into the reactnative code?

Comment: issue being: "appState": "Waiting for an animation to finish. Continuous animations may never finish and must be stopped explicitly. Animations attached to hidden view may still be running in the background.\nWaiting for view's draw or layout pass to complete."

Comment: Can you check this one https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/691#issuecomment-384827723